# Помогите реализовать градиент через css

Tags: css, css3, градиент

Подскажите как сделать такой градиент, что бы к углам он становился полностью прозрачный. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Он таким тонким и будет?

Answer (score 2):

```css
body {
  background: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/7QFOe.png') no-repeat;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.overfade {
  margin-top: 55px;
  height: 50px;
  width: 1280px;
  border-left: 1px solid #000;
  border-right: 1px solid #000;
  background-image: 
    linear-gradient(
      to right, 
      rgba(172, 172, 172, 0) 0%, 
      rgba(172, 172, 172, 1) 35%, 
      rgba(172, 172, 172, 1) 65%, 
      rgba(172, 172, 172, 0) 100%), 
    linear-gradient(
      to right, 
      rgba(236, 234, 238, 1) 0%, 
      rgba(236, 234, 238, 1) 50%, 
      rgba(172, 172, 172, 0) 50%, 
      rgba(172, 172, 172, 0) 100%);
  background-position: 0px 55%, 0px 0px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% 3px, 100% 55%;
}
```

```html
<div class="overfade"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

что то такое?

```
background: rgb(226,226,226); /* Old browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, rgba(226,226,226,1) 0%, rgba(209,209,209,1) 9%, rgba(209,209,209,1) 9%, rgba(209,209,209,1) 21%, rgba(209,209,209,1) 34%, rgba(254,254,254,1) 66%, rgba(254,254,254,1) 66%); /* FF3.6-15 */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(226,226,226,1) 0%,rgba(209,209,209,1) 9%,rgba(209,209,209,1) 9%,rgba(209,209,209,1) 21%,rgba(209,209,209,1) 34%,rgba(254,254,254,1) 66%,rgba(254,254,254,1) 66%); /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(226,226,226,1) 0%,rgba(209,209,209,1) 9%,rgba(209,209,209,1) 9%,rgba(209,209,209,1) 21%,rgba(209,209,209,1) 34%,rgba(254,254,254,1) 66%,rgba(254,254,254,1) 66%); /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#e2e2e2', endColorstr='#fefefe',GradientType=1 ); /* IE6-9 */
```

Comment: по краям нету прозрачности

Comment: Ну так почитайте, как это исправить, я вам показал направление.

Comment: Спасибо что показали направление и я вам благодарен за ответ, но это не такая простая задача как кажется, я пробывал использовать css свойство mask но с ним не получался нужный ефект, поэтому и обратился сюда, так как не знал куда еще можно обратится. В интернете ничего не нашел

Answer (score 1):

в сети есть много сервисом для генерирования градиентов вот например один из них [Ultimate CSS Gradient Generator](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/). В редакторе можно сделать что то на подобие такого

```css
div {
  /* Permalink - use to edit and share this gradient: http://colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/#000000+0,000000+10,000000+89,000000+100&0+0,0.65+9,1+89,0+100 */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.65) 9%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.65) 10%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 89%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 100%);
  /* FF3.6-15 */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.65) 9%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.65) 10%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 89%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 100%);
  /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
  background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.65) 9%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.65) 10%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 89%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 100%);
  /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#00000000', endColorstr='#00000000', GradientType=1);
  /* IE6-9 */
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но дело не в самом градиенте, а именно в равномерном исчезновение градиента по краям

Comment: поиграйтесь с сервисом, там все можно сделать. на картинке, которую Вы скинули скорее всего радиальный градиент с переходом от серого к прозрачному

Answer (score 1):

```css
div {
  overflow: hidden;
}

div:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  height: 8px;
  margin-top: -4px;
  background: radial-gradient(ellipse at center, silver 0%, transparent 80%);
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```